# Scope with 2 different conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, scope, backend

I would like to filter stories on my index based on 2 different conditions where one is for the Current Country and the other one is for All Countries. Is it possible to create a scope where it could fetch stories for both this condition ?

All Countries is boolean field where in my Story table. The logic is if the Story is created for all countries the field, all_countries = 1

Featured Item model, is where the stories could be featured on the index page if the writer would like to do so.

This is how my model looks like for now with the scopes

```
    class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :stories 
    end 

    class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :countries
     has_many :featured_items, dependent: :destroy
     scope :by_country, lambda { |id| where(:country_id => id)}
     scope :for_all_countries, where(:all_countries => true)

    end

    class FeaturedItem < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :story
     scope :by_country, -> (country) {joins(:story).where('`stories`.country_id = ?', Country.find(country) )}
     scope :for_all_countries, -> { joins(:story).where('`stories`.all_countries = ?',true) }
    end
```

p/s the scope for all countries on the featured Items also returns an error.

Comment: Can you post the error message as well?

Comment: I don't think you need the find in this - `scope :by_country, -> (country) { joins(:story).where(:stories => { :country_id => country } ) }` should work for id or country instance

Comment: I think its the back ticks... Try this instead. `scope :by_country, -> (country) {joins(:story).where('stories.country_id = ?', country.id )}
     scope :for_all_countries, -> { joins(:story).where('stories.all_countries = ?',true) }`

Comment: But I would still be return with 2 different scopes. I was wondering if I could create one scope with both the conditions where the stories are available for the current_country where its meant to be for the current_country and for all countries.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this sort of thing:

```
scope :by_country, -> (country) { country == :all ? where(:all_countries => true) : where(:country_id => country) }
```

You may need to add a little more logic to handle bad params.

And for the join table, you can join and filter on the stories.

```
class FeaturedItem < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :by_country, -> (country) { (country == :all ? where( :stories => { :all_countries => true } ) : where( :stories => { :country_id => country } ) ).joins(:story) }

end
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked for the Story model. But how bout for Join tables ? Which is for the Featured Item model. the current scope by for the current country looks like this and I would like the code to also scope for all countries   `scope :by_country, -> (country) {joins(:story).where('`stories`.country_id = ?', Country.find(country)}`

Comment: Updated with a scope for the FeaturedItem

Comment: Thanks , but it returns the queries where the story has the current_country id && all_countries == true. The stories which is needed to be displayed are the stories for the current country and for all countries.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand, you would like to pass in country and get back all stories that either have that country_id OR have all_countries: true?

Answer (score 1):

Your [`scope`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) syntax is currently wrong, as is your pluralization of the `belongs_to` association.

You'll need to use the following (`@swards` answer is right, this is just an addition):

```
#app/models/story.rb
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :country
   scope :countries, ->(ids = :all) { ids == :all ? where(all_countries: true) : find(ids) }
end
```

This will allow you to call `Story.countries` to return all countries, and `Story.countries(1,2,4,5)` to return individual ones.

> filter stories on my index based on 2 different conditions where one is for the Current Country and the other one is for All Countries.

Have you considered using the following in your `Country` model:

```
@stories = @country ? @country.stories : Country.stories

#app/models/country.rb
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :stories
   scope :stories, -> { joins(:stories).where(story: {all_countries: true}) }
end
```

Comment: Thank you but this code worked for me in filtering the stories for the current country and for all 
`scope :by_country, -> (country) {joins(:story).where('`stories`.country_id = ? or `stories`.all_countries = 1', country) }`